# Assigning an array to alternatingItemColors in Flash Builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have an issue regarding alternatingItemColors in a list. I want to assign an array to alternatingItemColors but as my array exists in the script above the components. The flex complier says cant access property colors the code is as follows:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
    [Bindable]
         public var colors:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();
colors=[#FFFF00,#fd8301];
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
<s:List id="workList" width="100%" height="40%"  alternatingItemColors="colors"/>
```

Can some one suggest what is wrong and how to assign the array to alternatingItemColors

Answer (score 0):

use Array (not ArrayCollection)

```
public var colors:Array = [#FFFF00,#fd8301];
```

also your binding tags are missing around colors

```
<s:List id="workList" width="100%" height="40%"  alternatingItemColors="{colors}"/>
```

Comment: did this answer your question?  Going through and checking answers to see how you faired?